# A question about an integral of complex variable function

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

$$∫_{(|z|=1)}z^{e^{z}/100}dz$$
Let $z＝e^{i\theta}$，then
it becomes

$$i∫_{-\pi}^{\pi}(e^{i\theta})^{\frac{e^{e^{i\theta}}}{100}}e^{i\theta}d\theta$$
But I don't know how to calculate it.
Hope for your help. Thanks.

Comment: The integral is closed, and is analytic everywhere inside the closed area. By Cauchy-Goursat the integral is zero.

Comment: Is it analytic at $0$

Comment: I assumed it was. I don't know how else this could be solved if it were not.